# TextView un-removed ChangeWatchers cause memory leak

Tags: android

We have Activities and Fragments leaking and have traced the cause back to what appears to be un-removed ChangeWatchers on TextViews.

Scenario:
Activity A starts Activity B.  B has a textPassword EditText field in its layout.  Activity B finishes.

The HPROF dump shows that there is still one instance of Activity B. Its gcroot path is the following:

```
test.maa.LoginActivity
'- mContext android.widget.EditText 
   '- this$0 android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher 
      '- [1] java.lang.Object[13] 
         '- mSpans android.text.SpannableStringBuilder 
            '- mSource android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod$PasswordCharSequence 
               '- mText android.text.MeasuredText 
                  '- mMeasured android.text.StaticLayout 
                     '- sStaticLayout class android.text.DynamicLayout
```

This also happens if you Linkify.addLinks to a TextView.

Is there any way to clean up Activity B?

Comment: You say "Activity B finishes" - how does it "finish"? Are you explicitly calling `finish()`, pressing the `BACK` button or another method?

Comment: test.maa.LoginActivity is B? Have you forced a GC before dumping the HPROF so you are sure that it's not simply not collected yet? Or just paused and still referenced see @MisterSquonkq

Comment: Further testing on different devices reveals that this problem occurs on GSlate running 3.1 but does not happen on Thunderbolt running 2.3.4

Comment: B Finishes by calling finish().

Comment: I click the GC button a few times before dumping HPROF

Comment: you say you are using fragments. Do both activities use the same instance of a fragment?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem on our app

Comment: Same problem here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348049/android-edittext-memory-leak

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this appears to be a bug in Android related to the TextView ChangeWatcher and Linkify or Html.fromHtml spannable strings.  I was able to work around the problem by calling `setText(null)` in my activity's onDestroy().  There may be other workarounds that work as well, but I wasn't able to find any further information on the leak.

Comment: I tried that, I cant seem to find anything to fix it been at it for days. see my post as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348049/android-edittext-memory-leak

Answer (score 0):

For us, the problem was caused by a `PasswordTransformationMethod` in the `EditText`. Specifically for us, it is wrapped in a `TextInputLayout`, so we have to toggle it there like so (this code is in a `Fragment#onDestroyView()`):

```
        TextInputLayout passwordTextInputLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
        if (passwordTextInputLayout.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled())
            passwordTextInputLayout.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(false);
```

Happening in androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Application Context instead of Activity Context in onCreateView() for this particular View (which contain any android:textIsSelectable="true" components).

```
// Singleton
class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication mApp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mApp = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getApp() {
        return mApp;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Suggested inflater use Activity Context
    // So we must tu use Application Context
    Context context = MyApplication.getApp().getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater myLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View view = myLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, container, false);
    return view;
}
```